# TypeError: ($scope.values || []).map is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I moved from AngularJS 1.4 to 1.6. 
Now i used these library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

I did required change in syntex of my code and everything work fine. Now
I got error in my old code. Values in scope is

```
$scope.values = [
    {"Filename":"DV8199-3D_cloud.xhtml","Filetype":"XHTML"},
    {"Filename":"DV8199-3D_cloud.xhtml","Filetype":"XHTML"},
    {"Filename":"SHIRT.xhtml","Filetype":"XHTML"},
    {"Filename":"DV8199 -3D_Default_c.png","Filetype":"colorways"},
    {"Filename":"DV8199 -3D_Default_c.png","Filetype":"colorways"}
]
```

I try to collect unique list of Filetype by this code.

```
$scope.getFiletype = function () {
    return ($scope.values || []).map(function (w) {
        return w.Filetype;
    }).filter(function (w, idx, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(w) === idx;
    });
};
```

It gives me type error that map is not a function. Filetype list will be used in dropdown to search(filter) by file type.

Comment: The code which you have posted in the question works fine, I think there is something which is not here in the question. Please log in the console Array.isArray($scope.values), it will make sure that it's an array or not.

Comment: It was due to typo. Thanks

Comment: code is working fine

Comment: Please close the question.